# ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'user'

Tags: angular

my routing doesn't work, an error pops up when I go to the "/ user" page "ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'user'"

```
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: '', component: ListUserComponent,  outlet: 'main' },
      { path: '', component: LeftProfileInfosComponent,  outlet: 'left' },
      { path: '', component: UserNavComponent,  outlet: 'nav' },
      { path: 'user', component: DetailsUserComponent,  outlet: 'main' },
      { path: 'user', component: LeftProfileInfosComponent,  outlet: 'left' },
      { path: 'user', component: UserNavComponent,  outlet: 'nav' },
    ]),
```

Comment: I think you should not have same path name. Please change them and test again

Comment: I deleted the duplicate paths and all the same

Answer (score 0):

Remove duplicate route and in component.html or your root HTML place

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Please provide outlet name properly.

You can go through below link

[https://www.techiediaries.com/angular-router-multiple-outlets/#:~:text=Auxiliary%20routes%20allow%20you%20to,a%20sidebar%20for%20the%20app](https://www.techiediaries.com/angular-router-multiple-outlets/#:%7E:text=Auxiliary%20routes%20allow%20you%20to,a%20sidebar%20for%20the%20app).